# Blender: Exporting a large 3D map into a 2D image

Tags: rendering

I have designed a 3D Map in Blender. I wish to export a 2D image where I can place it inside an HTML5 canvas. The user would then be able to pan across the canvas to see the whole map.

My question is, how do I export the whole blender map into a 2D image? I can fit the whole map into the camera view port but it would be too small. I can even export the 3D map into small segments, but I am not sure how to do that either.

I am still new to blender and don't know all its features.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to rcgauer's answer, in the camera's settings you'll likely want to change its lens from perspective to orthographic if you want it to be a flat 2d view from above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender's ability to render large images is pretty robust: We do images 10Kx10K and larger all the time, so your viewport view is not a limiting factor.

Set up your camera to view the entire map, either overhead or however you wish to see the map inside your final 2D image. Set Blender's render dimensions to something large enough to accomplish your readability goals. This could easily be many thousands of pixels in either or both dimensions. Hit render.

[image]

You may want to experiment with camera settings to get the best image possible. Also, remember that if you are using an image texture within the 3D map (say, a 1024 x 1024 image as a ground texture), Blender cannot magically render it 20K x 20K without pixelization.  We use 4K skins and higher when we are working on big images... If procedural textures accomplish what you need, you'll have no problems.

Hope this helps... big images are a real strength of Blender, and shout if I can assist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was looking at this the wrong way. Once again thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to put up with learning a little bit of blender version 249b there exists an add-on called "really big render" that allows you to create a huge image. Granted it is exported in six separate photographic files but you can combine all into one by importing all 6 into Gimp or Photoshop, lining them up, and merging all layers into one, or flattening the image which is of high quality. Warning: I was only able to make it work once. This add-on crashed and never worked again. I don't know why. But i was able to create a high quality poster artwork using it. Just try the add-on on a different computer that has 249 installed on it. Do some research. You'll. Find the add-on somewhere.

Comment: DVed because it is not a helpful answer. Rendering huge images is not an issue, nor do you need a special addon.